# Added some columns to a SQL Server 2008 R2 table but it does not show up when a web page queries the table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I've added some columns to a table in SQL Server 2008 R2. I then put some default values into these columns. Then I selected these columns with a query which produced the expected results in the output box. My issue is when I use the following lines of code

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["abc"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    this.abcHyperLink.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);
}
else
{
   this.abcHyperLink.NavigateUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["abc"].ToString();
}
```

to query the new columns, it produces this error message

> Column 'abc' does not belong to table Table.

When I use the same code with old columns, the code works fine and retrieves the correct data.

Why can't I query the new columns but I can with the old columns? Is there something else I have to do the new columns before I can query it with the code? Your help is much appreciated

EDIT:

The SQL query to check if the new columns were added is

```
Select [abc],[xyy]
from [database].[dbo].[table]
```

EDIT2:
    The app calls

```
public DataSet GetDataSet()
{
    string sql = "use [name of db] exec sp_search_by '" + this.searchString + "'";
    DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer();
    return dataLayer.GetDataSet(sql, "BCITConn");
}
```

which calls

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, string db)
{
    string providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ProviderName;
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
    DbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        dbConnection = factory.CreateConnection();
        dbConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ToString();
        DbCommand dbCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.CommandText = sql;
        dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 2000;
        dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
        DbDataAdapter dbDataAdapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
        dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        dbConnection.Close();
        dbConnection.Dispose();
        return dataSet;
    }
    catch (DbException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dbConnection != null)
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
            dbConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

which uses

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BCITConn" connectionString="Data Source=[correct]; Initial Catalog=[name of db];User ID=[correct];Password=[correct]; Max Pool Size=1000000; pooling=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

from the web config

Comment: What query are you using? Can you put it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the column you are querying is not being rendered perhaps you aren't mentioning your column in the query.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not appearing though. Say I query an old column with the C# code and I get '123'. I update the sql server entry to '456', and I query the column again. I will instantly get '456'. I just dont understand why the code works with every old column but not with the ones that I newly added

Comment: Have you added the new columns in your SELECT statement in the code? If you have there is no reason it shouldn't appear there. Can I have a look at the whole code where you are querying to the database and fetching results?

Comment: I didnt use code to add the new columns. I used the sql server 2008 R2 interface. i clicked on the table I wanted to add the columns in. Right click it and select design and added the columns that way. Should I have used alter table instead?

Comment: No, it's not that, I want to know how you are querying in C#, in your application code. How do you generate the DataSet ds

Comment: I've added the code you requested. Sorry for the delay. I don't have access to the code from home

Comment: It seems you are calling the SQL Query in a procedure. try sp_search_by in SQL Server and see if the column appears in the result.

I think you should update the SP in SQL Server as well